# element inside td is not taking td full height if table height is auto

Tags: javascript, html

inside td I am taking a table, but somehow table is not taking the td full height. can any one help me to fix this issue.

html for table:

```
<table style="height: auto">
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: red">
                <table style="background-color: orange">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div style="height: 20px; width: 2px; background-color: black; vertical-align: top"></div>
                            <div style="height: 2px; width: 20px; background-color: black; vertical-align: bottom"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height: 100%;">
                        <td>
                            <div style="height: 100%; width: 2px; background-color: black;"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="background-color: yellow">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Description</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Expression</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a table structure of two columns , first column is to draw links and other column is to display the data. based on the second column data I want to arrange the links. for links I took a table with two rows. first row height should be fixed. and second row has to take reaming height.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force an object to take up 100% of the height of a cell without writing some JavaScript that will figure out the height of the cell and resize the table programatically.

I'm not really sure what your goal is with this, but you can achieve the look you seem to want by setting the background on the td and set a border to get the red outline.

```
<table style="height: auto">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: orange; border: solid red 1px">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="height: 20px; width: 2px; background-color: black; vertical-align: top"></div>
                        <div style="height: 2px; width: 20px; background-color: black; vertical-align: bottom"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 100%;">
                    <td>
                        <div style="height: 100%; width: 2px; background-color: black;"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color: yellow">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Expression</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to create a table structure of two columns , first column is to draw links and other column is to display the data. based on the second column data I want to arrange the links. for links I took a table with two rows. first row height should be fixed. and second row has to take reaming height.